# Finding the directory of the debug folder

Tags: vb.net

Currently in VB.NET it autocompletes the location of the debug folder and you don't have to physically locate it every time that the location is needed. My question is, how do I find that location manually in VB.NET?

This is a problem for me as my program needs to be stored on a portable medium so it can be transferred between computers easily and drive letters are subject to change. I want the program to find this location each time it starts so that I can just manually determine it each time and errors won't occur.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: It seems that you want to store a physical path, this is not a good practice. Use only relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about

```
Application.StartupPath()
```

?

Sorry if i misread.

Comment: Yep thats what I wanted

Comment: Okay then, glad i could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at DirectoryInfo (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(".").FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I have no issue when moving a VB project around. To keep the file you're handling in a safe place, I usually keep the file name to a simple string (no hard coded file locations). If you do this, you should be able to find your file in:

ProjectName -> bin -> Debug -> FileName

For example:

```
Dim FileName As String = "My_File.txt"

My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FileName)
```

And My_File.txt will always be in Debug. No matter what drive or location it is on.